# passing custom javascript object property as parameter in function to update

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to pass a javascript object's property to a function to update the value of the property?  Right now I have an object like...

```
element = { 
   border: { 
     width:0
   }
}
```

I'm trying to pass in an instance of this object to a function to update the width property but it's not working.  Something like...

```
var instance = new element();
UpdateWidth(instance.border.width, 50);
```

I'm guessing inside the function it's just getting the value of instance.border.width and not the property itself.  Is this possible to do?  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't `UpdateWidth(instance.border, 50)` make more sense anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I would attach the function to the object like so:

```
function element() { 
       this.border: { 
         width:0
       },
       this.updateBorderWidth: function (newWidth) {
           this.border.width = newWidth;
       }

    }
```

then do this:

```
var instance = new element();
instance.updateBorderWidth(50);
```

I am not sure however why this is necessary if you can acces the instance properties directly unless you want something else to happen when the width is updated. On a further note, if you wish to create classes and inheritance in Javascript I would look at this:

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: The issue I'm running into is that the sample code I gave is extremely simplified.  My object actually has around 20 properties at the moment with more coming.  And all of them need updated by selections on a web page.  For example, I have five sliders on the page that will control the border width (all, top, right, btm, left).  I have the sliders wired up in my jquery document ready event to update the the object's border right property when the right border slider is moved.  So, all of these properties are in an array that are passed to the jquery each function to wire to the slider.

Comment: I've tried doing something like this as a callback function.  In my jquery each loop it is calling the function and passing in the value but when it gets inside the function the value is now undefined.  I'm using firebug to watch the calls so I'm not sure why it's coming in as undefined to the function.  Any idea?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass primitive values (e.g., number literals, `0`) by reference. Objects, on the other hand, can be -- such as the one stored in the `border` property:

```
UpdateWidth(instance.border, 50);
```

Granted, this will require `UpdateWidth` to be something like this:

```
function UpdateWidth(subject, width) {
    subject.width = width;
}
```

But, if the function is about that simple, you can just set the `width` property directly without needing reference passing:

```
instance.border.width = 50;
```

---

However, you can't create a new instance directly from an existing object:

```
var element = { };
var instance = new element(); // TypeError: object is not a function
```

You can use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) in modern browsers (or with a polyfill):

```
var instance = Object.create(element);
```

Otherwise, you need to declare it as a constructor:

```
function Element() {
    this.border = {
        width: 0
    };
}

var instance = new Element();
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible.  Direct access is the easiest through assignment operator.

In your case: obj.obj.prop = value;

Below are some examples, I use a function to create the Object to more explicitly show what is going on versus using JSON notation.  See Jonathan's answer for more on the inability to instantiate an object from an existing one in the manner you are trying to.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script language="javascript"type="text/javascript">

    function init() {

        function e() {
            var obj = new Object();
            obj.border = new Object();
            obj.border.width = 0;
            return obj;         
        }

        var x = e();

        var y = e();

        y.border.width = 12;
        document.write(y.border.width);
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write(x.border.width);

        function UpdateWidth( obj, a ) {
            obj.border.width = a;
        }

        UpdateWidth( y, 50 );
        document.write("<br/>");
        document.write(y.border.width);

    }



    window.onload = init;

    </script>

</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```